# xenial: remmina unable to connect via rdp to win 10 vdi

Tags: networking, 16.04, remote-desktop, rdp

Remmina (supplied host name, userid, pw, domain, security=rdp) gives the subject response.

Also, per other posts, xfreerdp gives the following response:

```
expected PDU_TYPE_DEMAND_ACTIVE 0001, got 0007
ERRINFO_SERVER_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES (0x00000009):
The user cannot connect to the server due to insufficient access privileges.
expected PDU_TYPE_DEMAND_ACTIVE 0001, got 0007
SSL_read: I/O error: Success (0)
```

Also, I tried rdesktop, but that simply hangs with no error report AFAIK.

Any suggestion for connecting to a Win 10 vdi from xenial appreciated.

Comment: are you following a guide? is your windows system properly set up for this connection? because it looks like windows is denying you access because the user is not allowed

Comment: @FrankSchrijver I'm able to connect to said Win 10 vdi from a separate Win 8 desktop.  I would like to confirm that remmina is sending the correct login info, thanks.

Comment: Do you have the ports open in the target system's router and firewall?

Comment: @Organic Marble Ports are open and working according to telnet, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script I use to connect to vdiW10 machine, it works for windows 7 as well for me:

```
xfreerdp /v:<remote machine name> /u:<username> /p:$(zenity \
--entry \
--title="Domain Password" \
--text="Enter your _password:" \
--hide-text) /d:<domain> /f /cert-ignore /microphone:sys:alsa /sound:sys:alsa +auto-reconnect /g:<gateway address>;
```

Update your info and paste it in the terminal, it working for 14.04 and 16.04 LTS.

Comment: 16.10?  That's not out yet...  Did you mean 16.04?

Comment: Yes corrected to 16.04. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides updating to the latest version of Remmina and dependents, my sys admin added access to additional resources on the server side.  As a result Remmina was able to connect - fyi, including specification of a gateway server.